# Implementing unique_ptr: Deleting non-allocated objects

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

My goal here is to implement a simple version of unique_ptr which offers only a constructor, destructor, ->, *, and release().

However, I don't know what to do in the case where a unique_ptr is initialized using a non-allocated pointer.

eg

```
int i = 0;
unique_ptr<int> p{&i};
```

If the unique_ptr simply calls delete on it owned pointer, this will produced undefined (and undesirable) behavior, at least as far as I know. What can I do to prevent this?

EDIT: My attempt at the problem is as follows...

```
template<typename T>
class Uptr
{
public:
    Uptr<T>(T* pt) : mp_owned{pt} {}
    ~Uptr<T>() {delete mp_owned;}

    Uptr<T>(const Uptr<T>&) = delete;
    Uptr<T>& operator=(const Uptr<T>&) = delete;

    T& operator*() const {return *mp_owned;}
    T* operator->() const {return mp_owned;}

    T* release() {return mp_owned;}

private:
    T* mp_owned;
};
```

Comment: The same is true for the **real** `unique_ptr`.  But to answer your specific question - you can't do anything, reliably/portably (at least not last time I was familiar with C++).

Comment: You could have a flag which controls whether you call delete or not, and set it when creating a unique_ptr on a stack allocated object. It does of course beg the question why you're creating unique_ptrs to stack allocated objects in the first place

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The point of a `unique_ptr` is that it is the sole owner of the resource. If the `stack` owns it, then a `unique_ptr` shouldn't point to it.

Comment: @Galik "Doesn't make sense" is not an excuse to not be thorough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot check programmatically how a pointer value was obtained. In your situation (which is highly representative of large parts of real programming!), the solution is to *document your interface* to *require* that the pointer value be deletable. You place a *precondition* on your users, which requires that your users read the documentation and follow it, and you do not and cannot provide in-language methods for validating those preconditions. You pass the burden on to your users.

Such precondition burdens always form a kind of "technical debt", and you want to avoid it as much as you can (but perhaps not at the expense of runtime cost). For example, in the standard library we would strongly discourage the use of the ownership-taking constructor of `unique_ptr` and instead as the user to use `make_unique`, which has no preconditions and results in a valid `unique_ptr` value. That design is exemplary for how you would manage technical debt in the real world.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do about this: the ownership of the object must be transferred to `unique_ptr<T>`, which is not possible if you use addresses of objects in global, static, or automatic areas.

The implementation from the standard library, i.e. `std::unique_ptr<T,Deleter>`, takes a deleter parameter, which you can use to *not* delete anything. However, this use is highly questionable, because in this situation you do not need `unique_ptr` at all.